# pull javascript code from csv file

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to pull some javascript code from a csv file, and run it inside my script. But the code isn't working and I'm getting the code returned as a variable.

This javascript code returns a random number from 5-10

```
var loopRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*5 + 5); loopRandom;
```

I tried putting it different ways in the csv file for example

```
(Math.random()*5 + 5)
```

then in my javascript I have this code

```
var loop = csvExtract;
var loopRandom = Math.floor + loop +; loopRandom;
alert(loopRandom)
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here exactly, maybe using eval will help you.

Comment: what is the type of your  csvExtract ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you made a typo here or it's the actual code, but there are several mistakes in that code:

- Math.floor is a method
- That +; in the second line
- Numbers read as string should be converted to numeric type
- That loopRandom floating there

But in order to help you with the code I need to know what are you trying to accomplish. Do you want to read and execute *the code* from the file, or just numbers to use in that sentence?